# Python - How to sort a list of strings

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I would like to sort this list:

`my_list = ["32,6,bob", "5,21,fred", "100,9,sid"]`

by the second number in each string in descending order. Like this:

`["5,21,fred", "100,9,sid", "32,6,bob"]`

I know I can change it to a list of lists and sort it like this:

```
my_list = [["32", "6", "bob"], ["5", "21", "fred"], ["100", "9", "sid"]]
my_list.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

But it's annoying to have to change it to lists and then string it afterwards (It's to be written to a file), so I was wondering if there's a way to sort it as strings.

Comment: On a side note, your code would be incorrect, you are sorting lexicographically not by the actual number value

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [1]: sorted(["32,6,bob", "5,21,fred", "100,9,sid"],
   ...:        key=lambda s: int(s.split(',')[1]),
   ...:        reverse=True)
Out[1]: ['5,21,fred', '100,9,sid', '32,6,bob']
```